# Cloning wordpress live site to localhost (mamp) - redirect to live site

Tags: wordpress, localhost, mamp

I am new in this and I am struggling with cloning a WordPress live site to localhost for development. After reading many different tutorials, I finally succeeded to clone the live site to localhost (http://localhost:8888) but when I try to login into the WordPress admin area at first it did not open at all but after trying a few times it opened but redirected to the live site.

I changed the URLs in phpmyAdmin but I always have the message "0 rows affected". I changed the URL in wp_config.php.

```
define('WP_HOME','http://localhost:8888');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://localhost:8888');
```

After this in phpMyAdmin inside my database --> wp_options I changed the *site URL* and *home* with the new localhost URL http://localhost:8888.

Nothing of these is working. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to make a clone by some plugin (f.e. Duplicator). It will makes for you all of the stuff like changing the url in DB, and if is anywhere a problem it gives you error report.

You can install Duplicator, make a full copy of you website (just clicking next...next), after that download it to your PC (or devie where is localhost). After that, run the downloaded php file and complete the DB login. After that, if you have correct DB with correct login credentials you should have running website copy on localhost.

More details you could find in this video: https://youtu.be/NLYyecIXOU0